# Ruby: Making a new line in the editor without breaking the program line

Tags: ruby, printing, line

So I am taking the Ruby lessons from Codecademy and I am trying to write this code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCRqt.png However, when I run the program in Terminal, I get the (Use NY for New York) part on a new line. How do I create a new line in my text editor without making a new program line?

EDIT: It appears I wasn't clear enough. Sorry, I am very new to this. Here is what I get in the cmd when I try to run the program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbC9E.png
I don't want the red parts on a new line. I want to keep them on the same line but to also have a new line in my text editor.

Comment: not clear , can you please give a more detailed explanation

Comment: Don't make people need to see a different page in order to understand your question.

Comment: It is not possible break is like end of line operator in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

using `\n`

```
print "hello \nworld"
```

you need to write :

```
print "So your last name is  #{last_name} and you\nlive in #{city}, #{state.upcase}. Is that correct ?"
```